# Pythonic way to add multiple calculated columns to a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a more succinct / pythonic / pandas-native way of writing the following?

```
all_pos = ['NN', 'VB', 'ADJ']
for col in all_pos:
    df_out['delta_'+col] = df_out[col] - mean_df[col]
```

`df_out` and `mean_df` contain the same column names and indices, and I want to create new columns in `df_out` containing the difference between them.

So `df_out` could contain

```
Index  NN VB ADJ

239    9  4  3
250    2  2  1
```

And `df_mean` could contain

```
Index  NN VB ADJ

239    3  1  8
250    7  4  3
```

I would want `df_out` to look like

```
    Index  NN VB ADJ delta_NN delta_VB delta_ADJ

    239    9  4  3       6        3       -5
    250    2  2  1      -5       -2       -2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple subtraction (no need to do it per column) and concat the input and output:

```
pd.concat([df_out,
           (df_out - df_mean).add_prefix('delta_')
          ], axis=1)
```

or

```
df1.join((df1-df2).add_prefix('delta_'))
```

`(df_out - df_mean)` can also be written `df_out.sub(df_mean)`

output:

```
       NN  VB  ADJ  delta_NN  delta_VB  delta_ADJ
Index                                            
239     9   4    3         6         3         -5
250     2   2    1        -5        -2         -2
```

NB. I assumed "Index" is the index, if not first run:

```
df_out.set_index('Index', inplace=True)
df_mean.set_index('Index', inplace=True)
```

Comment: You can also use `df1.join((df1-df2).add_prefix('delta_'))`.